# Is there anyway to set the relationship of many tables from Model?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to set the relationship of some tables and make some columns in the table can be null.

```
[Table("tbl_useraccount")]
public class AccountViewModels
{
   [Key]
   public string AccountId { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string HashPassword { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the table which I want to make relationship:

```
[Table("tbl_userprofile")]
public class UserProfileViewModels
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string AccountId { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
   public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

My question is: How to set `AccountId` (in the table `tbl_useraccount`) is the primary key and as the foreign key in the table `tbl_userprofile` from Model?

And my sub-question is: Is it necessary to set `NULL` or `NOT NULL` for per column name? If it is necessary, how can I do that?

p/s: I'm using MVC 5 and SQL Server.

Comment: Are you using entity framework?

Comment: Yes. I'm using EF 6.

Comment: Use nullable types for allowing nulls otherwise they will be NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

First remark I have is that you don't use viewmodels for your database generation. ViewModels are only used for your views.

To create a relationship, you should add the AccountModel to the UserProfile, I added virtual to enable lazy loading. Also add the ForeignKey data annotation to the extra property you want to map your key to (optional)

```
[Table("tbl_useraccount")]
public class AccountModel
{
   [Key]
   public string AccountId { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string HashPassword { get; set; }
}


[Table("tbl_userprofile")]
public class UserProfileModels
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string AccountId { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("AccountModel")]
   public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

   public virtual AccountModel AccountModel { get; set;}
}
```

If you want a field not to be null, if this is even possible. Use the [Required] data annotation. "Public int PhoneNumber" can not be null, you'll have to write it as following: "Public int? PhoneNumber".